# call a function every time you click to change output value

Tags: javascript, function

I have this exercise that I am stuck on 
they asked me to make a function that change the day every time you click the button 
here's what I made but I can't figure a way to call the function every time I click 
the question was to not use any library 
here's my script

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>
    <title> change it</title>
</head>

<body>
    <a>today is</a>
    <a id='demo'></a>
    <script>
        var s = 0

        function add(s) {
            if (s < 6) {
                s + 1
            } else {
                return s = 0
            }
        }
        var days_of_week = ["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday",
            "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"
        ]
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = days_of_week[s];
    </script>
    <br><input type="button" value="next day" onclick="add(s)">
    <script>
        console.log(days_of_week[s]);
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Few changes below. I added storing new `s` value and moved changind day name into function.

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>
    <title> change it</title>
</head>

<body>
    <a>today is</a>
    <a id='demo'></a>
    <script>
        var s = 0

        function add(s) {
            if (s < 6) {
                return s + 1
            } else {
                return s = 0
            }
        }
        var days_of_week = ["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday",
            "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"
        ]
        function changeDay(s) {
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = days_of_week[s];
        }
        changeDay(s);
    </script>
    <br><input type="button" value="next day" onclick="window.s = add(s); changeDay(s);">
    <script>
        console.log(days_of_week[s]);
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```